# Do-while loop hangs the connection to website

Tags: php, do-while

I am trying to use do-while loop to check if a value exists in database,

```
function check($a) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE code = '$a'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$nm = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($nm > 0) {
return true;
} else {
return false;
}
}

function randomnumber() {

    $chars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz023456789";
    srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
    $i = 0;
    $pass = '' ;

    while ($i <= 10) {
        $num = rand() % 33;
        $tmp = substr($chars, $num, 1);
        $pass = $pass . $tmp;
        $i++;
    }

    return $pass;

}

$number = randomnumber();

do { $number = randomnumber(); } while (!check($number));
```

That codes somehow hangs the connection to website. After i execute this page, strangely it cannot connects to website until i restart the browser.

What may cause this ?

Comment: ...Or a small number of available options.  What does `randomnumber()` return? Did you debug it?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yeah i included it here

Comment: You're definitely going to want to put an upper limit on the number of times that that loop runs, but more likely you're going to want to re-evaluate how this piece of code is written. `random != fair`, your function could return nothing but `a` from now until eternity, and if there's no `a` in your database, then your code is going to run eternally. It's not *likely* to happen, but it's *possible*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query is never evaluating to true, so the loop is infinite.  As long as it's not pulling back any rows `where code = 'yourRandomNumber'`, then you will be looping indefinitely.

Comment: In other words, the logic is backward.  `while (check($number))` instead of `while(!check($number))` since `check()` returns `true` if the code already exists, not `false`!

Comment: The thing is i want it to break loop if code doesn't already exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply select a random 'code' from your database this code will be *much* more efficient than what you've got.

```
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT code FROM `table`';
$result = mysql_query($query);
$my_arr = array();
while($row = $mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $my_arr[] = $row['code']
}

$random_key = $my_arr[array_rand($my_arr)];
```

Re-reading your question and comments I'm less and less sure what your code originally set out to accomplish, if you could be a bit more clear on your objective here we could probably give you some advice on how to accomplish your goal more efficiently.

### Edit:

This code will retrieve all of the codes already used in your table, calculate the difference from the possible codes, and then return one random unused code. No loop required. [well *one* loop, but it's a short one]

```
$psbl_codes = str_split("abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz023456789");

$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT code FROM `table`';
$result = mysql_query($query);
$used_codes = array();
while($row = $mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $used_codes[] = $row['code']
}

$unused_codes = array_diff($psbl_codes, $used_codes);

echo "random unused code: " . $unused_codes[array_rand($unused_codes)];
```

Comment: i meant that i just try to check random-number if exists in the database with do-while until it finds that random-number doesnt exists.

Comment: @RULE101 I've added a bit of code that should accomplish what you need without the need for a potentially long-running loop.